# Why are there no FPGAs with built in USB interfaces?

Tags: usb, fpga

There is no shortage of micro-controllers with built in USB interfaces, but there do not appear to be FPGAs with built in USB interfaces.

Are there technical reasons for this, or is it just that the companies don't perceive a profitable market for USB FPGAs?

Personally, I can think of many of projects for which a low cost USB FPGA would be quite useful.

Comment: because then it would be a SoC not an FPGA... There are plenty of SoC out there that provide functionality outside of a flexible programing fabric

Comment: You can synthesize usb hardware, FPGA are meant to be field-programmed.

Comment: There are, just like you have FPGAs with Ethernet, DDR ionterface,  ARM cores etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 1/ It is a disguised rant. 2/ It is about commercial equipment . 3/ No prior research.

Comment: @Oldfart, I'm not sure what you mean about no prior research.  Do you want me to include a list of unsuccessful google searches?  As you yourself mentioned, FPGAs include many different hard coded blocks. However, there are no USB interfaces.  There could be a technical reason, there could be an economic reason, it could be ignorance to a market opportunity.  How is asking an honest question a rant?

Comment: A general purpose USB stack requires significant software (And is far more easily done in software then as a FPGA style state machine), so you should be looking for things like the Zynq where there is a hard IP CPU already, many of these have an interface for a USB PHY. The PHY is generally external for much the same reason very few people put ethernet PHYs on die even when building processors with built in ethernet MACs (Noise sensitivity, need for really robust ESD measures, analogue stuff).

Comment: @crj11 There are FPGA's with USB interfaces more of the slower ones. You could implement USB yourself but you'd need a transceiver fast enough, and then you'd still need the appropriate driver. Most people use UPLI for usb 2.0 for the faster USB.

Comment: @oldfart, a *rant* is to "speak/shout at length in an angry, impassioned way". The OP made a perfectly calm and reasoned point. ('rant' is very overused and misused on this site.) Indeed, the vast majority of FPGAs sold do not have USB interfaces, unlike for microcontrollers. There is no demonstration of a clear lack of research - the OP asked why not, not which ones do. Please can we stick to the site's agenda and help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A general purpose USB interface really needs software in play, it is HARD to do as a FPGA style FSM.

USB physical layer is also 5V, and modern processes are pushing the upper limit even at 3.3V, there are basically no 5V capable FPGA parts using modern processes.

Further, particularly for relatively high speed IO over cable interfaces (Like say 480Mb/s) the cable equaliser and driver are essentially in some sense analogue, so you need a process node that supports 5V analogue design AND 1V high density in something like 28nm or such for the core.

Comment: Mostly agreed, but the USB physical layer is not usually 5 V. The USB spec requires a minimum V_oh of 2.8 V, so most transceivers run off of 3.3 V. (Of course, Vbus is typically 5 V, but that's separate.)

Comment: @AbeKarplus, USB requires 5V tolerance on interface wires. True, the mandatory requirements to withstand a continuous short to 5.25 V was lifted in 2008, but it still "is recommended". If you want a robust computing platform that doesn't die on every device attachment, you better have robust USB interface silicon.

Comment: @AliChen Most transceivers don't bother with 5 V tolerance, though. They should, sure, but it's rare.

Comment: Lattice recently introduced an FPGA with a built in USB interface.  See https://www.latticesemi.com/about/newsroom/pressreleases/2023/lattice-introduces-industrys-first-small-embedded-vision-fpga-with-integrated-usb

Answer (score 6):

First of all, there ARE FPGAs with USB interfaces, so your premise is flawed. However, they tend to be high-end SoC devices where the tight integration is worth the premium cost.

For low-cost, low-end systems, it usually makes more sense to marry a USB microcontroller with a separate low-end FPGA or CPLD. Such systems tend to have a large software component anyway, so using dedicated hardware for both the CPU and the USB is more efficient.

The USB PHY interface is not integrated into FPGAs because modern FPGA processes can handle 3.3V at most (sometimes with limited 5.0V I/O compatibility), but USB PHY requires full 5.0V input and output.

Comment: Can you give me a link to an FPGA with an integrated USB interface?

Comment: Search for Xilinx Zynq or Intel Arria.

Comment: As far as I can tell, these devices require an external PHY.  Do you disagree?

Comment: Nope. See @DanMills' comment on your question.

Comment: That still begs the question why they can put PHYs on dirt cheap MCUs but not FPGAs.  To me the most likely reason would seem to be process incompatibility.

Comment: That, plus the fact that it makes no sense to put just a phy on a low-end FPGA. You still need a CPU to implement the other layers of the USB protocol stack.

Comment: You don't need a CPU if you have an internal hard USB interface like an FTDI chip.

Comment: An FTDI chip has a CPU in it.

Comment: @crj11 FTDI chips are generally very much fixed function (And are probably really small microcontrollers under the hood). A general purpose USB interface really needs software in play, it is HARD to do as a FPGA style FSM. USB physical layer is also 5V, and modern processes are pushing the upper limit even at 3.3V, there are basically no 5V capable FPGA parts using modern processes. I also don't recall many micros with on board PHYs capable of any real speed, IIRC it all seems to be 12Mb/s, not 480Mb, there is a reason for that.

Comment: @DanMills: Cypress, among others, has High Speed and Ultra Speed USB chips.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks Dave, useful to know, I was looking a little while ago and at the time did not find much in single chip with high speed integrated PHY, but I had not checked Cypress.

Comment: @DanMills, thanks for the most reasonable answer to the question, i.e. that it is a process incompatibility due to the 5V nature of the USB interface.  If you are so inclined, you can convert it into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: As others have noted, USB is *not* 5V.

Comment: @SodAlmighty: While it's true that the data signaling is 3.3V, Vusb is 5V +/-10%, and that is an important part of the initialization and enumeration protocol.

Comment: Vusb is irrelevant. The host does not care if you use it or not. Either use a linear regulator, or get power from somewhere else. 3.3V chips can and regularly do have native USB support.